# Identify groups of equal consecutive elements in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

Lets say we have a sorted array,

```
A = [1,2,2,3,7,7,7,9]
```

We want the output to look like:

```
[1]

[2,2]

[3]

[7,7,7]

[9]
```

This is my attempt:

```
def func(A):

    j = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        result = []
        while A[i] == A[j] and j < len(A)-1:
            result.append(A[j])
            j += 1
        if result != []:
            print(result)
```

This function doesn't include the last element in the list and also has running time O(N^2) which I'm trying to improve on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`itertools.groupby` is a very convenient way to group similar elements in a list:

```
>>> A = [1,2,2,3,7,7,7,9]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for group in groupby(A):
...     print(list(group[1]))
...
[1]
[2, 2]
[3]
[7, 7, 7]
[9]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, never seen this before. But I'm trying to solve this problem without importing.

Answer (score 2):

you could solve your problem with `for loop` and `two if's`:

Here is the code:

```
def func(A):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        result.append(A[i])

        if i == len(A)-1:
            print (result)
        
        if (i != len(A)-1) and (A[i] != A[i+1]):
            print (result)
            result = []
```

Your provided input:

```
A = [1,2,2,3,7,7,7,9]
```

Your output will be:

```
[1]
[2, 2]
[3]
[7, 7, 7]
[9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function with O(N) time (I'm pretty sure at least):

```
def func(A):
    last_num = A[0]
    last_list = []
    for num in A:
        if last_num == num:
            last_list.append(num)
        else:
            last_num = num
            print(last_list)
            last_list = [num]
    print(last_list)
```

Instead of using a nested for loop, this loops through each element and stores the last number into a variable `last_num`. If the current number is the same as the previous number, then it is added to `last_list`. Otherwise, everything is reset and `last_list` is printed. At the end, `last_list` is printed again as there is no number after to activate the `else` statement (which prints the list out).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
L = len(A)
if L > 0:
    prev = A[0]
    print ("[", prev, sep="", end="")

for i in range(1,L):
    if prev != A[i]:
        print ("]")
        prev = A[i]
        print ("[", prev, sep="", end="")
    else:
        print (",", A[i], sep="", end="")
else:
    print ("]")
```

**Output:**

```
[1]
[2,2]
[3]
[7,7,7]
[9]
```

Comment: It does work, yet I think it would be better if you were to use actual python lists instead of using strings (I'm pretty sure OP wants the lists, not just the strings).

Comment: @AyushGarg -- What makes you so sure? In OP's code the list that is being constructed is only being printed, and not being returned. I don't see any point in building a list by repeated `append()` calls, if its purpose is to only print. Anyways, we could let OP comment on that aspect of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) that returns consecutive keys and groups (as generators) from the iterable:

```
from itertools import groupby

for _, group in groupby(A):
    print(list(group))
```